# Create and name new sheet from list containing blanks

Tags: vba, excel

I am needing help in writing a macro that will create a new sheet based on a named range (ARK_E_TEXAS_LIST). The new sheet names will come from column A in the named range, however, that column will contain blanks but column C will have data in all the rows. Unfortunately, this is how I need the list to be.

Is it possible to create the new sheets and name them from column A and pass over the blanks?

```
        A       B           C    
   1    AR0000RK            BLDG CPLX 1
   2            AR0030RK    SUB BLDG 1
   3            AR0063RK    SUB BLDG 2
   4            AR0082RK    SUB BLDG 3
   5            AR0085RK    SUB BLDG 4
   6            07020850    SUB BLDG 5
   7    TX0000TY            BLDG CPLX 2 
   8            TX0182TY    SUB BLDG 1
   9            TX0262TY    SUB BLDG 2  
   10           07020830    SUB BLDG 3
   11   AR0021ZZ            BLDG 1  
   12   AR0031ZZ            BLDG 2
   13   AR0057ZZ            BLDG 3
   14   AR0062ZZ            BLDG 4
   15   AR0066ZZ            BLDG 5
   16   AR0078ZZ            BLDG 6    
   17   AR0079ZZ            BLDG 7
   18   AR0084ZZ            BLDG 8
   19   TX0019ZZ            BLDG 9
   20   TX0126ZZ            BLDG 10
   21   TX0130ZZ            BLDG 11
   22   TX0210ZZ            BLDG 12
   23   TX0404ZZ            BLDG 13
```

```
Sub Create_ARK_E_TEXAS()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim newSheetName As Range
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim Lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ARK_E_TEXAS")
Set newSheetName = sht.Range("A1:A")
Lastrow = sht.Range("ARK_E_TEXAS_LIST").Rows.Count
Set dataRange = sht.Range("A1:C" & Lastrow)

For Each newSheetName In dataRange
**If newSheetName > 0 Then
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = newSheetName.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Else: End If**
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = newSheetName.Value ' renames the new worksheet
Next newSheetName
End Sub
```

Comment: Add an `if` within the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
For Each newSheetName In dataRange
    If newSheetName.Value <> "" Then 
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = newSheetName.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    End If
Next newSheetName
```

Comment: Well I almost had my correction right. Thanks nwhaught. And I will not know it if until I can fix my error of newSheetName not pulling the data.

Comment: Glad to help. If your question is solved, please mark the answer as accepted. (click the checkmark) :-)